# How to remove active from button when open other button

Tags: jquery

Code:

```
<li class="submenuList item-with-ul selected">
      <a href="#">Blalab</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav flexnav-show" style="display: block;">
        <li><a href="#">Highlights</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Invited</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Talks</a></li>
      </ul>
    <span class="touch-button active"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down navicon"></i></span>
    </li>
```

script:

```
$('.touch-button').on('click', function(e) {
      var $touchButton;

      $touchButton = $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').find('>span.touch-button');

      $parent = $(this).parent('.item-with-ul');

      $(".flexnav ul").removeClass('flexnav-show').hide();

      $(this).parent().not('.selected').addClass('selected');
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

      //couldn't figure how to remove active from touch-button and add active as so to close and open the submenu
      //$(this).removeClass('active');
      // $touchButton.removeClass('active');
});
```

Managed to remove/add selected when click on button for other sub-menu list. But for button to be still in active state when click on next button for next sub-menu list. Couldn't get the active to be removed or added when click on next button.

Not sure why it is not working (see commented lines)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simply,

```
$('.touch-button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.touch-button').removeClass('active');// remove active from all touch-button
    $(this).addClass('active'); // current touch button is active only now
)};
```

I think what you need is,

```
$('.touch-button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.touch-button').removeClass('active');
    $('.item-with-ul').removeClass('selected');
    $('.flexnav-show').hide();
    $(this).addClass('active') // make current touch button active
           .closest('.flexnav-show').show() // show the closest ul
           .closest('.item-with-ul').addClass('selected'); //add the selected class to list item
});
```

Comment: almost but not there because when click on same button twice it will not show selected class for example. Also while click on next by next button, it also won't show submenu

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('.touch-button').on('click', function(e) {
 $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
$('.touch-button').removeClass('active');// remove active from all touch-button
$(this).addClass('active'); // current touch button is active only now

});
```